# Which preposition should follow "guide" here, "on," "to," or "for"?

Tags: prepositions

> The following link includes a guide *___________* how to use it.

How should I fill in the blank, *on*, *for*, or *about*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Generally* speaking, I personally prefer "guide to" over "guide on"; "guide about" sounds rather strange to me (though not ungrammatical).

By the way, mohang's Google results are very different from what I'm seeing:

- ["guide to"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22guide+to%22) — 171,000,000
- ["guide on"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22guide+on%22) — 6,530,000
- ["guide about"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22guide+about%22) — 485,000

(If I add an article in front of "guide" to make sure that I only get results where it is a noun, the picture is the same: 119,000,000 vs 4,730,000 vs 252,000 for "a", and 15,500,000 vs 2,380,000 vs 156,000 for "the".)

I checked the [British National Corpus (BNC)](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), and they both seem to agree:

```
                   BNC   COCA

guide.[n] to      1419   4553
guide.[n] on        37    194
guide.[n] about      4     15

guide to how        41     27
guide on how         6     16
guide about how      1      1
```

That being said, as Rocquie points out, two "to"s in rapid succession are not everybody's thing. I actually agree, so *in this particular case*, I would probably go with "on" (as Bruno suggests) or with "to" + gerund:

> - a guide on how to use it
> - a guide to using it

The BNC stats look as follows:

```
guide on how to     6
guide to how to     4
guide about how to  0

guide to using/getting/making     3/4/7
guide on using/getting/making     0/0/0
guide about using/getting/making  0/0/0
```

Now, what about "guide for"? That one is trickier, because it usually means something else entirely — more often than not, the *for* denotes the target audience rather than the subject of the guide (though the latter is not unheard of, either). Here are just a few examples from BNC and COCA:

> - The Guide for the Perplexed

- A Guide for Married Couples
- a Resource Guide for the Responsible Non-Monogamist
- Evaluating the School: A Guide for Secondary Schools in the Metropolitan Borough of Solihull
- Licensing Digital Content: A Practical Guide for Librarians
- A Green Guide for Travelers
- How to Win an Election: An Ancient Guide for Modern Politicians
- a copy of Practical Guide for Asthmatics

You can't meaningfully substitute *to*, *on* or *about* in any of these examples.

Answer (score 4):

People would in general use **on**.

There are [many definitions of "on" in the Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on?show=0&t=) dictionary. The definition to support "on" as the preposition choice in this case is:

> Used as a function word to indicate
>   the subject of study, discussion, or
>   consideration (a book on insects)

Answer (score 2):

I would just say "a guide **explaining** how to use it" and avoid the unnecessary awkwardness.

Answer (score 1):

*To* sounds clumsy because of the other *to*. *On* is fine, *about* is OK but two syllables so not as concise as *on*.

Answer (score 0):

Why not *a guide to*?

I checked Google search; the following are the results:

1. *guide on* -> 1,910,000,000
2. *guide to* -> 1,940,000,000