# "Instructions on" vs. "instructions for"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following is correct?

> - Instructions *on* how to do this will be provided in the User Manual.
> - Instructions *for* how to do this will be provided in the User Manual.

Comment: "Instructions **on** *how* to do this will be provided in the User Manual."  

"Instructions **for** *the correct way* to do this will be provided in the User Manual."

Comment: Just "Instructions will be provided in the User Manual" could be simpler.  e.g. "The user must register, log in and post a question.  Instructions will be provided in the User Manual." The instructions refer to the procedures in the previous sentence.

Comment: Related: [“Guide on” vs. “guide for” vs. “guide to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4184/which-preposition-should-follow-guide-here-on-to-for).

Comment: On another aspect, do you mean that the User Manual has not yet been written?  If it has, why not "Instructions **are** provided in the User Manual"?

Comment: Or, "How-to instructions are in the User Manual" (36 characters versus 55 or 56 in OP's examples).  Sometimes economy of expression can be a good thing.

Comment: How about *"Instructions for doing this ..."*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you to everybody who has added comments. The intention of my question was not to find a better wording to the sentence, but to understand the correct usages of 'on' and 'for', which Kris's answer cleared up perfectly!

Edit: As it may disappear, the comment that answered my question best was as follows:

> Instructions ***on* how to do this** will be provided in the User Manual.
>
> Instructions ***for* the correct way to do this** will be provided in the User Manual.

Comment: This isn't an answer! Comments can disappear; they are ephemeral by design. If there is an answer you have adopted from comments, please give that answer as an answer.